# How to solve this equation with three variables arithmetically?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How can we find the sum of $x$, $y$, and $z$ arithmetically?
$$x+y=6$$
$$z+y=10$$
$$x+y+z=?$$

Some things I have tried:
$$y=6-x$$
$$y=10-z$$
$$6-x=10-z$$
$$z-x=4$$
or
$$x+2y+z=16$$
or
$$x=6-y$$
$$z=10-y$$
$$x+z=6-y+10-y$$
$$x+z=16-2y$$
Will these lead me anywhere?

Answer (score 5):

Just having $x+y=6$ and $y+z=10$ is not enough information to determine $x+y+z$.

For example, we could have $(x,y,z)=(6,0,10)$ with sum $16$, or $(x,y,z)=(-10,16,-6)$ with sum $0$.

In general you can get *any sum you want* by setting $(x,y,z)=(t-10,16-t,t-6)$, giving a sum of $t$.

Even if, for example, you want $x$, $y$ and $z$ all to be positive, you can still get any $t$ strictly between $10$ and $16$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can solve this is using matrix row operations.
Place the systems of equations in to a 3x4 matrix and solve.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&2&0&6\\
      0&1&1&10\\
      1&1&1&a
      \end{array}
\right] $$

Where $a = ?$
And the columns represent $x,y, z$ respectively.